# Do dipole dipole interactions need to be added explicitly to vdW forces while doing DFT simulations for organic molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, density-functional-theory

I  am modelling the adsorption of organic molecules on metal surfaces using plane-wave dft. While there is literature on how important van der Waals forces are for organic systems, and there are also some corrections to incorporate vdW forces into DFT (DFT-D, DFT-TS, and so on...); I was wondering if these corrections incorporate electrostatic dipole-dipole interactions within them (or do the dipole-dipole terms need to be added separately)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Permanent dipole)-(permanent dipole) interactions are covered by the electrostatics of DFT (and Hartree-Fock, for that matter, because no [Coulomb] electron correlation is involved). In my opinion, interactions between a permanent dipole (such as the one of HCl) and an instantaneous dipole (methane) are covered by the parametrization of dispersion-accounting methods in an averaging fashion.